# How to generate new own list in an internal table?

Tags: abap

**List in the internal table at the beginning:**

```
code | name | sum
 22  | Jon  | 234.3
 22  | Jon  | 34.2
 22  | Jon  | 0
 22  | Jon  | 0
 12  | Bob  | 999.4
 12  | Bob  | 0
 45  | Anna | 0
 45  | Anna | 0
 11  | Mike | 0
 11  | Mike | 234.3
```

**To get the output of such a list from the internal table:**

```
code | name | sum
 22  | Jon  | 234.3
 22  | Jon  | 34.2
 12  | Bob  | 999.4
 45  | Anna | 0
 11  | Mike | 234.3
```

**Conditions for the formation of a new (outgoing) list:**

1. If the column ***name*** with several identical names (for example with four - **Jon**) has a value (column ***sum***) 34.5 ... and 0, then throw away all 0 and print only non-zero.
2. If the column ***name*** with several identical names (for example two - **Anna**) has a value (column ***sum***) 0 - then print only one name with the value 0.
3. The list can not be sorted - the output must have a list with the same order as the input.

Comment: Let's see some code, brother! :)

Comment: @ andreas I'm just a beginner in ABAP, so help me out the algorithm and if you know what standard methods can be used to solve the problem?

Comment: There is no standard methods as you have custom requirements. Just LOOP and DELETE, only hardcore! Don't try others to do your job for you.

Comment: @András  can not be sorted, the new list must be in the order in which it was before

Comment: @Suncatcher I don't try others to do my job, I just described a problem that I do not understand and asked how to solve it

Comment: I am not asking if I can sort the table, I am asking if all Jon's rows are next to each other

Comment: @András Yes, all Jon's rows are next to each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm considering `lt_grp1` will contains beginning internal table records. And i've declared `lt_grp2` of same structure as `lt_grp1`.

```
  DATA: lv_index TYPE i VALUE 0.

  APPEND LINES OF lt_grp1 TO lt_grp2.
  DELETE ADJACENT DUPLICATES FROM lt_grp2 COMPARING code name.

  LOOP AT lt_grp2 INTO ls_grp1.

    LOOP AT lt_grp1 INTO ls_grp2
          WHERE code = ls_grp1-code
            AND name = ls_grp1-name.
      lv_index = lv_index + 1.
      IF ls_grp2-sum = 0.
        IF lv_index > 1.
          DELETE lt_grp1 INDEX sy-tabix.
        ENDIF.
      ELSE.
        IF lv_index > 1.
          DELETE lt_grp1 WHERE sum = 0
                          AND code = ls_grp1-code.
        ENDIF.
      ENDIF.
      CLEAR: ls_grp2.
    ENDLOOP.
    CLEAR : lv_index.
  ENDLOOP.


  CLEAR :ls_grp1.
  LOOP AT lt_grp1 INTO ls_grp1.
    WRITE: / ls_grp1-code, ls_grp1-name, ls_grp1-sum.
  ENDLOOP.
```

Hope this helps!

For those who think i didn't tested it.

Here is **input table** -

[image: Input table]

**Output -**

[image]

Comment: `lt_grp2 = lt_grp1` is significantly faster than `APPEND LINES OF`

Comment: @András Because i need only one jon, thats why i'm copying in another internal table. first understand the code. what its doing.

Comment: @András I know what is specification. I think you are having hard time understanding the code. I've given the test results in edits.

Comment: @András I'm deleting from only one internal table, Not from both.

Comment: @divScorp why do you check twice -> `IF lv_index > 1. ... ENDIF.` in your code?

Comment: the runtime of this is proportional with n^3

Answer (score 0):

This has O(n log(n)) runtime.

```
lt_copy = lt_original.
SORT lt_copy BY code name ASCENDING sum DESCENDING. "if there is a non-zero line, it is at the top "
DELETE ADJACENT DUPLICATES FROM lt_copy.

LOOP AT lt_original INTO DATA(ls_original).
  IF ls_original-sum = 0. "only 0 lines need to be checked"
    READ TABLE lt_copy ASSIGNING <fs_max_sum> BINARY SEARCH
        WITH KEY code = <fs_original>-code
                 name = <fs_original>-name.
    IF <fs_max_sum>-sum = 0.
      "there are only zeros for this code and name, we need it"
    ELSE.
      DELETE lt_original.
    ENDIF.
  ENDIF.
ENDLOOP.
```